# Python-FastAPI-SocketIO - 403 forbidden

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

I am trying to implement socket programming using Python, FastAPI and SocketIO.
When i try to connect to send the socket connect request the application is showing 403 error.

My code:

```
import socketio
from app import server
sio = socketio.Server()
apps = socketio.WSGIApp(sio,server)

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected")


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disonnected")
```

Postman Image:
[image]

Please let me know where i was wrong and please provide any sample codes you may have.

Comment: Can you share how you are running the server?

Answer (score 3):

I found this way to integrate socket.io with fastapi. First create a function like this:

```py
# socket.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from socketio import ASGIApp, AsyncServer


def socketio_mount(
    app: FastAPI,
    async_mode: str = "asgi",
    mount_path: str = "/socket.io/",
    socketio_path: str = "socket.io",
    logger: bool = False,
    engineio_logger: bool = False,
    cors_allowed_origins="*",
    **kwargs
) -> AsyncServer:
    """Mounts an async SocketIO app over an FastAPI app."""

    sio = AsyncServer(async_mode=async_mode,
                      cors_allowed_origins=cors_allowed_origins,
                      logger=logger,
                      engineio_logger=engineio_logger, **kwargs)

    sio_app = ASGIApp(sio, socketio_path=socketio_path)

    # mount
    app.add_route(mount_path, route=sio_app, methods=["GET", "POST"])
    app.add_websocket_route(mount_path, sio_app)

    return sio
```

Then you can use it with your fastapi app:

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from socket import socketio_mount


app = FastAPI()
sio = socketio_mount(app)


@sio.on("connect")
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("socket connected: ", sid)


@sio.on("disconnect")
def disconnect(sid):
    print("socket disconnected: ", sid)
```